# A way to navigate to different pages according to hub tile created from the application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating a project network dashboard in which I am creating hub tiles of network setting.

When I pin to start tile from my app. and whenever from home screen I click to tile it should navigate to different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add [secondary tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202979%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to your home screen you need to provide an URI, put some parameters in it:

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/EntryPage.xaml?param=wifi", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
```

Create an empty entry page (`EntryPage.xaml`) and in [`OnNavigatedTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method read parameters from uri and redirect to OS settings page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.New)
    {
        throw new Exception("exit");
    }
    string parameter;
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("param"))
    {
        parameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["param"];
        GoToOSSettigsPage(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer. The reason is: when you press back, you are being navigated to you EntryPage again and it redirects you back to Network settings page. You need to brake the loop.

Comment: See the explanation in comments, and an the solution in answer

Comment: there is a Zero with two arrows on the left side of my answer. ant you can see a gray check mark. Click it.